# How to cross compile a C++ library for windows to use it with Java JNA?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, cross-compiling, jna

I'm trying to use the C++ library Spot (https://gitlab.lrde.epita.fr/spot/spot) in a Java project. I wanted to realize the interface between Java and C++ with JNA (https://github.com/java-native-access/jna). Because the Java application should also run on Windows, I tried to cross compile the library first with

```
./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-python LDFLAGS="-static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc"
```

and then of course make/make install on a Linux system. Because I can't expect the Windows system to have libstdc++/libgcc I wanted to link it statically into the library. My problem is now the following: When I try to open an compiled .exe in Windows, it still tells me libstdc++/libgcc not found. Of course, JNA also gives me an UnsatisfiedLinkException when I try to load the library in my Java program, because the modules are still not found, even though i explicitly linked them statically.

So what am I doing wrong? What else can I try to avoid having libstdc++/libgcc installed on the host system? I am now trying this for a week and have no clue how to overcome this, so a question here is kind of my last resort.

Thanks

Comment: The sources of this kind of issue are extremely hard to determine in my experience. Your best guess would be to first have a successful compilation natively. 

If your main OS is Win this should be very easy to do using [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10): no need for your source files to move, only dependencies differ.

Comment: You should provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with c++ and Java code -  you probably  don't even need it to use the spot library.